# Jquery Mobile asp.net webservice parameter

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ContactList.asmx/GetContacts",
    data: "{'start':" + 1 + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
         console.log(msg.d);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('[data-url="' + tempdataurl + '"] div[data-role="content"]').html("Error loading article. Please try web version.");
    }
});
```

how can I send Muttiple paramater? I have 2 parameter start and count . please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
data: {start: 1 ,count:5}
```